# Openaphid Flipview Implementation

Tags: android, flip, flipview, flipboard

Im having trouble in using this [library](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip). I want to implement it in our capstone project (Students Handbook in Android). I've only manage to import the library in my Android studio.  I cant figure out what to do next.

I've already search for tutorials but I only got [this](http://www.ahotbrew.com/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android-tutorial/). I believe that this tutorials lacks information I need. Can anyone help me how would I apply this library to our application?

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to import the library successfully, then to make this component work its pretty much like using a ListView. Just instantiate your view, add it to your ViewGroup and bind it with your adapter (say ArrayAdapter) that will contain your pages.

```
FlipViewController flipView = new FlipViewController(yourContext, FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);
yourContainer.addView(flipView);

yourAdapter.addAll(yourItems);
flipView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: where would i put this code?(in my mainActiviity?)and what kind of view will i use for my pages?

Comment: can you give me a link with similar tutorial using listview?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) (amongs many tutorial) gives you the basics of how to build a ListView using an ArrayAdapter

Comment: ok,thank you,ive already make it work,the next thing is how will i use it with fragments?

Comment: If you managed to make it work from inside your Activity, then you just need to move your code into your Fragment. A Fragment has the same lifecycle as an Activity. Then add your fragment into your activity and you should be all set ;)